# Python - Sklearn mean using another column as variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to replace all the 'nan' values using the mean option within the SimpleImputer:

```
    imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', verbose=0)
    imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
    X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

(basically getting the mean of my first and second columns)
However, I need the mean to consider Column 0 (industry).
X being:

```
Col 0 = Industry
Col 1 = # of Employees
Col 2 = # Budget
```

Is there a way to achieve this using the SimpleImputer option?

- Replacing column 1 nan values with the mean by industry
- Replacing column 2 nan values with the mean by industry

Thanks

Edit:
Additional data for X:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('Group A.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
```

Comment: Please post a sample of `X`. Is `X` a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: That's not a sample we can use. We don't know what `Group A.csv` contains. Instead, include the output of `dataset.head().to_dict()`. Also post your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think fitting the imputer on the `industry` column should to the trick:

`imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 0])`

While doing transform as before.